# .NET Core change authorize attribute in inherited class

Tags: .net-core, attributes, asp.net-core-webapi, authorize

I have a base controller in ASP.NET Core 5:

```
public class ParentController : BaseController
{
   [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
   public virtual IActionResult Index()
   {
      return null;
   }
}
```

and a child class like this

```
public class ChildController : ParentController
{
   [Authorize(Roles = "User")]
   public override IActionResult Index()
   {
      return null;
   }
}
```

My problem is when I log in by a user that has `User` role when call index from the child I got 403 forbidden error.

Is there any way to change `Authorize` attribute in a child class?

Comment: According to your scenaio you could use [`policy base authorization`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-6.0). You could have a look on the [`sample here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Answer (score 0):

Your polymorfism is not correct in this case. You need create a special controller

```
public class ParentChildController : BaseController
{
     public virtual IActionResult Index()
   {
      ... your code
   }
}
public class ParentController : ParentChildController
{
   [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
   public override IActionResult Index()
   {
      return base.Index();
   }
}

public class ChildController : ParentChildController
{
   [Authorize(Roles = "User")]
   public override IActionResult Index()
   {
      return base.Index();
   }
}
```

or IMHO it is better to create an Authorization filter instead of an attributes. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-6.0#authorization-filters

Comment: so we can not override Authorize attribute like a function?

Comment: @MasoodZamani Polymorphism is working for virtual functions, there are no virtual attributes.